# Displaying records of a particular month in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I am trying to fetch records of a particular month from the database and the pattern of the data that column is ""

Query I am using is

```
select * from table_name WHERE column_name LIKE ''
```

for the month of September. But this is printing no results.

Please suggest.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: you can use `MONTH(column ) = monthNumber`

Comment: Colum data type is integer

Answer (score 3):

Use direct date comparisons!  Don't treat dates as strings.  So something like:

```
where column_name >= '2000-09-01' and column_name < '2000-10-01'
```

Or, if you want *all* months, then extract the month.  The standard function is `extract()`:

```
where extract(month from column_name) = 9
```

or:

```
where month(column_name) = 9
```

However, the particular function depends on the database (not all databases support all the standard functions).

Comment: Hi. I dont think all these solutions would work as I have to use this query for my back end c# code and select month from the dropdown. I am using this query in my .cs file under the onselectedindexchange event of the dropdown.

Comment: What options specifically do you have on your drop-down? Are you having your users selecting January-December or  01-12?

Answer (score 0):

Building up on the answers and comments above. It seems like you want to use this in your C# code with the user selecting a value from a dropdown. One option would  would be something like this:

```
  string monthNumber = valueFromDropdown;
  string connectionString = "put you connection string here";
  string commandText = "select * from table_name "
        + "where month(column_name) = @MonthNumber";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
        command.Parameters.Add("@MonthNumber", SqlDbType.Int);
        command.Parameters["@MonthNumber"].Value = monthNumber;

        try
        {
          connection.Open();
          using(SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
          {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
              Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}",
                 reader[0], reader[1]));
            }
          }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```