# How filter my table using months on my combo box vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio

I want to filter my table by month
I have my combo box that is connected to my transaction table
[combobox list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeK33.png)

This my transaction table
[Transaction table column transaction_added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7j0It.png)

I want my combobox has only months for example the whole month of October 2021 just like on my image
then if I choose October all the transaction on October will be seen on my table

this is my code on getting the dates and add it to my combo box list

```
            Try
                con.Open()
                cmd = New MySqlCommand("select * from tbtransaction", con)
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
                While dr.Read
                    Dim datem = dr.GetString("transaction_date")
                    cmbdate.Items.Add(datem)
                End While
                con.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                con.Close()
                MsgBox(ex.Message, vbCritical)
            End Try
```

Comment: Why are you selecting * when you only are using the transaction_date field?

Comment: Why are you storing dates as strings in your database?

Comment: It is a bad idea to update the user interface while the connection is open.

Comment: I used string storing dates so that I can see clearer date on my data gridview table just like the sunday, October 9 2020 @Mary

Comment: I can edit later the select * @Mary

Comment: If you had stored the date data as date you could have easily extracted the month. You have made things difficult for yourself.

Comment: Ill change that to date but I have a follow up question how can I extract it to a month and put it on the combobox? @Mary

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63793805/displaying-records-of-a-particular-month-in-mysql

Comment: If you want to show the dates in that format, you could use the valuemember of the combobox to store the value you want to pass to SQL (which could be formatted in a better way to interact with the database). MySQL, has a Month() function that will return the month of a passed date as a number (so for October, it returns 10). You could add this to your select statement, taking the month of the valuemember of the combobox (which could be a normal date like 10-11-2021 instead of how you currently have it displayed.  Just adding my two cents, @Mary is correct on all of her points.